# Updating Hierarchical Numbering

Tags: c#, mongodb, dynamic, hierarchical-data

I have below classes in my application which holds hierarchical data as below:

```
Class A 
{
   string Id{get;set;}
   string Name{get;set;}
   string Order{get;set;}
   string ParentId{get;set;}
}
Class B 
{
   string Id{get;set;}
   string Name{get;set;}
   string Order{get;set;}
   string ClassAId{get;set;}
}
Class C 
{
   string Id{get;set;}
   string Name{get;set;}
   string Order{get;set;}
   string ClassBId{get;set;}
}
```

Sample data for class A would be

```
Id = "1.1"                   Id = "2.1"
Name = "SomeName"            Name = "Name2"
Order = 1                    Order = 1
ParentId = "1"               ParentId = 2

Id = "1.2"                   Id = "2.2"
Name = "Name2"               Name = "Name3"
Order = 2                    Order = 2
ParentId = "1"               ParentId = 2
```

Sample data for Class B would be

```
 Id = "1.1.1"                   Id = "2.1.1"
    Name = "SomeName"            Name = "Name2"
    Order = 1                    Order = 1
    ParentId = "1.1"               ParentId = 2.1

    Id = "1.2.1"                   Id = "2.1.2"
    Name = "Name2"               Name = "Name3"
    Order = 2                    Order = 2
    ParentId = "1.2"               ParentId = 2.1
```

Similarly for Class C, data would look like

```
Id = "1.1.1.1"                   Id = "2.1.1.1"
Name = "SomeName"            Name = "Name2"
Order = 1                    Order = 1
ParentId = "1.1.1"               ParentId = 2.1.1
```

Now if user wants to update a value in between the existing values, the way it should work is, suppose I am entering a value between 1.2 and 1.3 for Class A, it should first create a new value called 1.4, then move all the contents of 1.3 and its children to 1.4 (i.e, if 1.3 has its own children like 1.3.1 so on and 1.3.1.1 so on all should be renamed to 1.4.1 and 1.4.1.1 respectively and 1.3 should be free of any hierarchy with empty value. Basically in between inserts should update the complete hierarchy of a record. I am able to generate next sequence correctly by finding current Id and finding maximum of order and adding 1 to it. Issue I am facing is in between inserts and updating whole hierarchy. 
Any ideas would help. Below is the code I have written for entering a new value Class A :

//Find the max order, increment it by 1 and insert the new record.

```
var currentClass = listOfClassA.Where(x => x.Id = currentId).SingleOrDefault();
var maxOrder = listOfClassA.Max(x => x.Order);
var objClassA = new A();
objClassA.Order = maxOrder + 1;
objClassA.ParentId = currentClassA.ParentId;
objClassA.Name = "";
objClassA.Id = currentClassA.ParentId + "." + objClassA.Order;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We decided to change our design to use dynamic expando objects and use them to generate the hierarchical numbering [Our requirements were to use dynamic collections (mongodb) and generate them on the fly]. Although the class structure will remain same as above. Below is the code we wrote for hierarchical numbering. This code takes the Id as input( like 1.1 or 1.2 or 1.1.1 or 1.1.1.1)

```
                dynamic expando = new ExpandoObject();
                var collectionModel = expando as IDictionary<string, Object>;

                var lastDotPosition = value.LastIndexOf('.');
                var parentId = value.Substring(0, lastDotPosition);
                collectionModel.Add("ParentId", parentId);
                var order = Convert.ToInt32(value.Split('.').Last());


                var newOrder = order + 1;
                var Id = parentId + '.' + newOrder.ToString();

                collectionModel.Add("Index", newOrder);//newOrder
                collectionModel["Id"] = Id;

                var filter = Builders<dynamic>.Filter.Gt("Index", order);
                filter = filter & Builders<dynamic>.Filter.Eq("ParentId", parentId);
                var collection = _db.GetCollection<dynamic>(collectionName);

                var remainingList = collection.Find(filter).ToList();

                var dynamicList = new List<ExpandoObject>();
                dynamicList.Add((ExpandoObject)collectionModel);
                // below updates the next record ids and parent id to ensure numbering is maintained
                for (int i = 0; i < remainingList.Count; i++)
                {
                    var remainingRecord = remainingList[i] as IDictionary<string, object>;
                    var newRecord = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, Object>;
                    for(int j = 0; j < listOfFieldNames.Count; j++)
                    {
                        var fieldName = listOfFieldNames[j];
                        Object dictValue = "";
                        remainingRecord.TryGetValue(fieldName, out dictValue);
                        if (fieldName == "Id")
                        {
                            newRecord[fieldName] = parentId + "." + (newOrder + 1);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            newRecord[fieldName] = dictValue;
                        }
                    }
                    newRecord["Index"] = newOrder + 1;
                    newRecord["ParentId"] = parentId;
                    newOrder++;

                    dynamicList.Add((ExpandoObject)newRecord);
                }


                //Now update child or grandchild if any

                var updateForChildList = remainingList.OrderByDescending(x => ((IDictionary<string, object>)x)["Index"]).ToList();

                for (int k = 0; k < updateForChildList.Count; k++)
                {
                    var oldRecord = updateForChildList[k] as IDictionary<string, object>;
                    var oldParentId = oldRecord["Id"];
                    Object dictValue = "";
                    oldRecord.TryGetValue("Index", out dictValue);

                    var newParentId = oldRecord["ParentId"] + "." + Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(dictValue.ToString()) + 1);
                    UpdateParentIdForChildren(oldParentId.ToString(), newParentId, Convert.ToInt32(collectionOrder + 1));
                }
                collection.DeleteMany(filter);
                collection.InsertMany(dynamicList);
```

Use recursion to find children and grand children and update their parentids and ids

```
public void UpdateParentIdForChildren(string oldParentId, string newParentId, int collectionIndex)
        {


            if (collectionIndex > collectionList.Count)
            {
                return;
            }


            var currentCollection = _db.GetCollection<dynamic>(collectionName);
            var filter = Builders<dynamic>.Filter.Eq("ParentId", oldParentId);
            var oldParentIdList = currentCollection.Find(filter).ToList();
            var reoldParentIdList = oldParentIdList.OrderByDescending(x => ((IDictionary<string, object>)x)["Index"]).ToList();
            if (reoldParentIdList.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < reoldParentIdList.Count; i++)
                {
                    var remainingRecord = reoldParentIdList[i] as IDictionary<string, object>;

                    Object OldIdValue = "";
                    remainingRecord.TryGetValue("Id", out OldIdValue);

                    Object indexValue = "";
                    remainingRecord.TryGetValue("Index", out indexValue);

                    var newId = newParentId + '.' + indexValue;

                    currentCollection.UpdateOne(filter, Builders<dynamic>.Update.Set("Id", newId));
                    currentCollection.UpdateOne(filter, Builders<dynamic>.Update.Set("ParentId", newParentId));

                    UpdateParentIdForChildren(OldIdValue.ToString(), newId, collectionIndex + 1);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea, as on your request, but wouldn't it be easier to include the classes into your hierarchical data structure, e.g.:

```
class A 
{
   public string Id{get;set;}
   public string Name{get;set;}
   public string Order{get;set;}
   //this is the tricky one.
   public string ParentId{get;set;}
}

class B 
{
   public string Id{get;set;}
   public string Name{get;set;}
   public string Order{get;set;}
   public A ClassA{get;set;}
}

class C 
{
   public string Id{get;set;}
   public string Name{get;set;}
   public string Order{get;set;}
   public B ClassB{get;set;}
}
```

---

Another idea: since your classes are very similar, you could also create a true hierarchical structure like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Id{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public string Order{get;set;}

    public Foo Parent {get;set;}
    public Foo Child{get;set;}
}
```

---

Expanding the previous idea, you'll find that you have created a sort of `LinkedList`, e.g.:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Id{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public string Order{get;set;}
}

var list = new LinkedList<Foo>();
```

---

Yet another option: which is a more `tree` like structure, I believe it's called the [composite pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern):

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Id{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public string Order{get;set;}

    public Foo Parent {get;set;}
    public IEnumerable<Foo> Children{get;set;}
}
```

I hope it helps. Using one of the above patterns will make it easy to produce the hierarchical ID string, like `1.2.3.4.e.t.c.`, if you even need it; because it's also very easy to serialize the whole thing. Beware of circular references though ;-)

Also the other operations, to find maxima or minima are quite doable, using `SelectMany` or recursive calls.

Comment: Thanks @Stefan. However we changed the design to use dynamic expando objects. I will be posting answer to this question below.